# How do you create a BLOB column in rails postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, blob

I'm attempting to store binary data in a database. (postgresql on heroku)

I understand there are two different ways to store binary data in postgresql. A blob and a bytea..

When I create a table in my migration,

```
create_table :binaries do |t|
  t.binary :data
end
```

it creates a column in the database of type bytea.

My question is.. How do I create a record of type blob?

Why do I ask? It seems when I send a ten byte file up to heroku, it stores it as a string of hex values, prepended with an "e".. so my 10 bytes becomes 21. My 10 meg file would become 20 megs (and one byte), ext, ext, ext... 
Now that bothers me, but as I don't really care about performance. (I've had the care beaten out of me by the PM), its not what bothers me the most.
What really bothers me is; when I read out the contents of the database I get the 21 bytes, not the 10. That is un-useable.

**So my question again.. How do I create a BLOB column in rails/postgresql/heroku environment?**

Comment: Please don't point out that I should be storing binaries as files.  Mine is not to reason why; mine is but to do or ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`bytea` is PostgreSQL's version of a BLOB. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html):

> The SQL standard defines a different binary string type, called `BLOB` or `BINARY LARGE OBJECT`. The input format is different from `bytea`, but the provided functions and operators are mostly the same.

So `bytea` is what you want. As far as the format goes:

> The `bytea` type supports two external formats for input and output: PostgreSQL's historical "escape" format, and "hex" format. Both of these are always accepted on input. The output format depends on the configuration parameter bytea_output; the default is hex. (Note that the hex format was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.0; earlier versions and some tools don't understand it.)

So what you're seeing is just the text versions that are used for getting data into the database and out of the database.

This might also be of interest:

- [ActiveRecord loads binary field incorrectly on Heroku, fine on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539207/activerecord-loads-binary-field-incorrectly-on-heroku-fine-on-osx/8541304#8541304)

Comment: THANKS!  Really really!  How do I get the data out in binary?  It's coming out "97" when I put in "a"

Comment: Found it.. and edited that answer... just to make it easier for the next noob.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539207/activerecord-loads-binary-field-incorrectly-on-heroku-fine-on-osx/8541304#8541304

Comment: This seems incorrect. Postgres has a separate BLOB type https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB. It is not the same as bytea which does not support streaming.

Comment: @ChrisNicola But Rails (AFAIK) doesn't know anything about [PostgreSQL's Large Object system](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/largeobjects.html) and LOs aren't really columns.

Comment: No, it doesn't have an higher level API but it is supported on the raw connection via `lo_open, lo_read, lo_write`. It would be pretty easy to write your own API on top of that though, it's just an OID reference. Also there is Carrierwave support https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql

Comment: @ChrisNicola: Do you want to expand that comment into an answer? I'd up vote it and encourage the OP to switch their accept if a LO is a better match for what they're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah I'm just setting it up for myself right now, when I'm done I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Blob storage is built into Postgres and is supported using the ActiveRecord adapter, but only directly through the raw connection and the `lo_*` methods. You can use `lo_write, lo_open, lo_close and lo_read` to create and manipulate blobs. Creating a blob returns an OID which you can reference the blob in your models.

You can add this using a migration

```
rails g migration AddFileToModel file:oid
```

Or directly like this

```
add_column :users, :avatar, :oid
```

For a working example of this you should look at the [Carrierwave PostgreSQL gem](https://github.com/diogob/carrierwave-postgresql). You can either build a custom solution based on that code, or just use Carrierwave directly. I'm currently using it and it works well.