# Binary data getting borked when saving to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'll let this irb session do the talking (junk omitted with `....`).

#### Create a model with some Marshalled data. `user_info` is a binary column

```
irb(main):011:0> p2 = Provider.create(user_info: Marshal.dump(ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({foo: 1, bar: 2}))
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (11.6ms)  INSERT INTO "providers" (...."user_info") VALUES (....$9) RETURNING "id"  [.....["user_info", "\x04\bC:-ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess{\aI\"\bfoo\x06:\x06EFi\x06I\"\bbar\x06;\x06Fi\a"]]
   (3.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Provider id: 98, ..... user_info: "\x04\bC:-ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess{\aI\"\bf...", provider_id: nil>
```

#### Check the value. Looks right:

```
irb(main):013:0> p2.user_info
=> "\x04\bC:-ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess{\aI\"\bfoo\x06:\x06EFi\x06I\"\bbar\x06;\x06Fi\a"
```

#### Bad things happen: here I reload it and the value completely changes into a format Marshal can't load

```
irb(main):014:0> p2.reload
  Provider Load (5.3ms)  SELECT "providers".* FROM "providers" WHERE "providers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 98]]
=> #<Provider id: 98, ...., user_info: "x0408433a2d416374697665537570706f72743a3a4861736857...", provider_id: nil>

irb(main):015:0> p2.user_info
=> "x0408433a2d416374697665537570706f72743a3a4861736857697468496e646966666572656e744163636573737b07492208666f6f063a0645466906492208626172063b06466907"
```

This session is running on Heroku after I recently moved my database from shared to their new free [Dev Postgres](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql).

I'm not sure if this is a heroku problem, a postgres problem or a rails problem. The strange thing is: I also migrated another instance (production) of the same app to the new Dev Posgress and it's not having this problem. I found [this](http://blog.aradine.com/2009/09/rubys-marshal-and-activerecord-and.html) but it appears to have been fixed years ago. Anyone have experience with this?

### Update

Looks like I found an answer after all from this excellent answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541304/65311

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord loads binary field incorrectly on Heroku, fine on OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539207/activerecord-loads-binary-field-incorrectly-on-heroku-fine-on-osx)

Comment: I'd be careful with using [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html) for things that go in the database. Normalization issues aside, the Marshal format changes over time so you could run into problems. JSON in a text column (or even [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)) would work better over time, YAML is another option.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. I plan to move to an `ActiveRecord::Store`.

Comment: The hstore version would be a good idea if you have hstore (I'm pretty sure all the PostgreSQL databases at Heroku support hstore these days): https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

Comment: Looks good. I suppose I'll need to move my local sqlite db to postgres  in order to use that. Unless AciveRecord::Store uses hstore underneath the covers for Postgres.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't though :/ http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Developing on top of one database and deploying on another is a recipe for disaster. Database independence is a nice idea but largely a myth unless you're willing to write to the lowest common denominator, test like crazy, and (usually) write your own portability layer.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. The biggest hurdle to running postgres locally though is getting my rails app running easily on non-technical designers' machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's docs explain how to configure the change for bytea in their newer databases at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#troubleshooting

Comment: I missed that. Thanks for the link. The thing I don't understand is why my production db continued using escaped after I migrated it from shared to Heroku Postgres, while my dev db didn't.